# Determine a curve's dominant direction over time

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I have a sequence of numbers in a certain order, for example
{60,61,62,1,63,,64,102,65,66,200}
If this is drawn as a graph, this will be a curve going upwards, but with some aggressive jumps upwards and downwards.

What I'd like to do is to disregard the abnormal data (1,102, 200) that doesn't belong to the dominant data density and be able to say that the dominant curve is going from 60 to 66 and I have a change of +10%.

Where can I start? Is there a procedure for that is statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of found an answer to this question

a smooth curve can be constructed from this noisy data using [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)

This is also called the sliding window technique